# Sending big files in Twisted

Tags: python, image, file, twisted

I have a really simple code that allows me to send an image from client to server. And it works.

As simple as this:

On the client side...

```
    def sendFile(self):
        image = open(picname)
        data = image.read()
        self.transport.write(data)
```

On the server side...

```
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print 'Received'
        f = open("image.png",'wb')
        f.write(data)
        f.close()
```

Problem with this is that only works if the image is up to 4.somethingkB, as it stops working when the image is bigger (at least doesn't work when gets to 6kB). Then, is when I see that the "Received" is being printed more than one time. Which makes me think that data is being separated in smaller chunks. However, even if those chunks of data get to the server (as I'm seeing the repeated print called from the dataReceived) the image is corrupted and can't be opened.

I don't know that much about protocols, but I supposed that TCP should be reliable, so the fact that the packets got there in a different order or so, shouldn't...happen? So I was thinking that maybe Twisted is doing something there that I ignore and maybe I should use another Protocol.

So here is my question. Is there something that I could do now to make it work or I should definitely change to another Protocol? If so...any idea? My goal would be sending a bigger image, maybe the order of hundreds of kB.

Comment: You need to send it in blocks. Keep the file open at the receive end and write each block as it arrives. It can arrive in differently sized blocks.

Comment: To send it in blocks, you can use FileSender protocol (http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.4.0/api/twisted.protocols.basic.FileSender.html)
 filesender = basic.FileSender()
 filesender.beginFileTransfer(data, self.transport)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variant of an entry in the Twisted FAQ:

- [Why is `protocol.dataReceived` called with only part of the data I called `transport.write` with?](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Whyisprotocol.dataReceivedcalledwithonlypartofthedataIcalledtransport.writewith)

TCP is a *stream-based* protocol.  It is delivering a *stream* of *bytes*, which may be broken up into an arbitrary number of *fragments*.  If you write one big blob of bytes, it may be broken up into an arbitrary number of smaller chunks, depending on the characteristics of your physical network connection.  When you say that TCP should be "reliable", and that the chunks should arrive in order, you are roughly correct: however, what arrives in order is the *bytes*, not the chunks.

What you are doing in your `dataReceived` method is, upon receiving each chunk, opening a file and writing the contents of *just that chunk* to `"image.png"`, then closing it.  If you change it to open the file in `connectionMade` and close the file in `connectionLost` you should see at least vaguely the right behavior, although this will still cause you to get corrupted / truncated images if the connection is lost unexpectedly, with no warning.  You should really use a framing protocol like AMP; although if you're just sending big blobs of data around, HTTP is probably a better choice.

Comment: Hey @Glyph, thanks for the answer. I tried the `connectionMade` - `connectionLost` method and it worked well, although...guess that if I want a reliable structure I shouldn't use that.

I would like to merge this feature with a larger project that I have that uses the TCP Protocol so if I could avoid changing all that code, would be great. Would be sending it in blocks, like @MartinEvans suggested, a good option here? Or that would still be in conflict with some sort of Twisted internal mechanism? Thanks again!

Comment: @josepmeg - sounds like you should ask another question - filling out the whole answer in the comment box here would be tough :).  When you do ask a new one, be sure to fill out exactly what your requirements are and why they are the way they are because I'm not sure I totally understand what "all that code" is, here.